# Finding exact match with equal sign with append function in SQL

Tags: java, sql

`sqlQueryString.append(" and upper(username) like upper(:searchString) ");`

This code returns data like exampleusername, exampleusername1, exampleusername12...

I want it to return data with an exact match to the username that is being searched.

For example when I put in bobJacobs (an example username), I want it to return only bobJacobs records, not other records that may contain bobJacobs in them, for example samandbobJacobs24, bobJacobs23, etc.

I've tried:
`sqlQueryString.append(" and upper(username) = upper(:searchString) ");`

But it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean that `=` "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: The query returns no results.

Comment: You'll need to show a runnable, minimal example which reproduces the problem.